# Datetime, pandas, and timezone woes: AttributeError: 'datetime.timezone' object has no attribute '_utcoffset'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, timezone

Here is a toy example of what I am trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')  # noqa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from time import sleep

lst = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    lst.append((datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc), x))
    sleep(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Timestamp', 'Pressure'])
df.plot(kind='line', x='Timestamp', y='Pressure')
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d %T %Z', tz=df.index.tz)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.savefig('output.png')
```

When I run this, I get `AttributeError: 'datetime.timezone' object has no attribute '_utcoffset'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Mostly scraped this from @AndyHayden [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703721/2864250), but one option is to convert `datetime.datetime` to `str` and convert back to "timezone aware" timestamp using `pd.to_datetime`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Timestamp', 'Pressure'])
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp.astype(str))
ax = df.plot(kind='line', x='Timestamp', y='Pressure')
plt.show()

df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d %T %Z', tz=df.index.tz)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: This fix works for me. 

Tickets [#12310](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12310), [#22859](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22859) seem to capture the issue, and not yet fixed. I plan on adding info to those tickets to give slightly clearer repro case.